# How to include a new .java file in my Android app project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, and I think that's simple, but I'm discovering the coding with Eclipse so I have this simple question :
How to include a new .java file in my Android project ?

My words are perhaps inapropriates, and to be more clear, I'm creating an Android application, and I want to include a .java file (located in *projectname/src/*)

Actually I have an unique file, *MainActivity.java*, and my application start fine.
I want to include a timer in my application, so I created a new *Timer.java* file in same folder, but when I start my app, it contain only data from this MainActivity.java file, nothing about my *Timer.jar* file.

So how I must declare the new file in my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply add it by right clicking on your src folder
[image]

you need to declare it on your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Timer"
        android:label="@string/title_timer" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
The thing I was missing was the AndroidManifest.xml